# QMessageBox and unicode character

Tags: qt, qt5, qmessagebox

I'm trying to display the [bullet character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) in a QMessageBox, but it renders as a typical "unknown" character (a `?` on a black background).

Here's how I try to do it :

```
QString message = QString::fromUtf8("\u2022");
QMessageBox::warning(this, "some title", message); // "this" is a QMainWindow subclass
```

I have tried to use the bullet character directly in source code with :

```
QString message = "•";
```

Visual Studio prompts me to save the file as Unicode, which is what I do, but the result is still the same.

I'm using Qt5.3 with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8.1, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
QString message = QString("This is the bullet character: %1").arg(QChar(0x2022));
```

Comment: That was so simple... Thank you !